# Hide Title bar in foreground and background

Tags: android

I want to hide title bar no matter is it in background or foreground. I've just tried this code but had error.Can somebody say what's wrong with my code?

This is error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.amadey.myapplication3, PID: 21769
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:249)
            at android.app.Activity.requestWindowFeature(Activity.java:3298)
            at com.example.amadey.myapplication3.Activity$AsyncCaller.doInBackground(Activity.java:31)
            at com.example.amadey.myapplication3.Activity$AsyncCaller.doInBackground(Activity.java:28)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

My code:

```
public class Activity extends Activity {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        new AsyncCaller().execute();

   }


    private class AsyncCaller extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Activity.this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot perform UI action in any thread except in *main* UI thread.

`Activity.this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` this line has to be in `onCreate()` method of your `Activity` class.

Also, you better change the name of your activity.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call requestWindowFeature after you call setContentView.  It has to be called before.  And it shouldn't be called from an AsyncTask at all.

Comment: But I want to hide title bar if my app is in the background.

Comment: If your app is in the background then you can't control whether the title bar is shown-  you don't own the screen.  If your app is in the foreground the place to do it is before setContentView is called.